# SQL for nvarchar 0 = '' & = 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was searching for integers in a nvarchar column. I noticed that if the row contains '' or 0 it is picked up if I search using just 0.

I'm assuming there is some implicit conversion happening which is saying that 0 is equal to ''. Why does it assign two values?

Here is a test:

```
--0 Test
create table #0Test (Test nvarchar(20))

GO
insert INTO #0Test (Test)
    SELECT ''
UNION ALL
    SELECT 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT ''

Select *
from #0Test

Select *
from #0Test
Where test = 0

SELECT *
from #0Test
Where test = '0'

SELECT *
from #0Test
Where test = ''

drop table #0Test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you see is the one describe din the product documentation. The rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) specify that `int` has higher precedence than `nvarchar` therefore the operation has to occur as an `int` type:

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence

Therefore your query is actually as follow:

```
Select *
from #0Test
Where cast(test as int) = 0;
```

and the empty string `N''` yields the value 0 when cast to `int`:

```
select cast(N'' as int)

-----------
0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Therefore the expected result is the one you see, the rows with an empty string qualify for the predicate `test = 0`. Further proof that you should never mix types freely. For a more detailed discussion of the topic, see [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I realized there was some conversion going on but couldn't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly converting the field to `int` with your `UNION` statement.

Two empty strings and the integer `0` will result in an int field.  This is BEFORE you insert into the `nvarchar` field, so the data type in the temp table is irrelevant.

Try changing the second select in the `UNION` to:

`SELECT '0'`

And you will get the expected result.

Comment: Same result, the select statement "where test = 0" still gets all three rows. I would think it should only by the one row of 0.

Comment: @BrettK - you need to use `WHERE test = '0'` - the numerical integer `0` evaluates to an empty string as well

Answer (score -1):

id-pkix  OBJECT IDENTIFIER  ::=
{ iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1)
security(5) mechanisms(5) pkix(7)[assets.example.com`

> `\]\[1\`],
> "participant_video_files": [
> {
> "id": "24698bd1-589e-4c33-9ba3-bc788b2a0ac2",
> "recording_start": "2021-12-07T05:42:13Z",
> "recording_end": "2021-12-07T05:42:28Z",
> "file_name": "recording_name",
> "file_type": "MP4",
> "file_extension": "MP4",
> "file_size": 900452,
> "download_url": "https://download.example.com/download_url",
> "recording_type": "individual_shared_screen",
> "status": "completed",
> "user_id": "abcd1234",
> "user_key": "efgh5678"
> }
> ]
> }

`}
Cooper, et al.              Standards Track                   [Page 110]

RFC 5280            PKIX Certificate and CRL Profile            May 2008

-- PKIX arcs

id-pe OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-pkix 1 }
-- arc for private certificate extensions
id-qt OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-pkix 2 }
-- arc for policy qualifier types
id-kp OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-pkix 3 }
-- arc for extended key purpose OIDS
id-ad OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-pkix 48 }
-- arc for access descriptors

-- policyQualifierIds for Internet policy qualifiers

id-qt-cps      OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-qt 1 }
-- OID for CPS qualifier
id-qt-unotice  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-qt 2 }
-- OID for user notice qualifier

-- access descriptor definitions

id-ad-ocsp=dev/null/**\0|I|D
OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-ad 1 }
id-ad-caIssuers
OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-ad 2 }
id-ad-timeStamping
OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-ad 3 }
id-ad-caRepository
OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {id-ad 5}